# DrawString method repeats a string twice

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I want this to take a given piece of text and display it as a paragraph correctly (jumping to new line when needed) using DrawString and for(;;) loop, but the result is bonkers.

```
private void pnlText_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pnlText.Font = new Font("Calibri", 14, FontStyle.Regular);
        SizeF lineSize = new SizeF();

        for (int i = 0; i < DisplayText.Length; i++)
        {
            currentLine += DisplayText[i];

            lineSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(currentLine, pnlText.Font);
            if (DisplayText[i].ToString() == " " && lineSize.Width >= 820)
            {

                paragraph += currentLine + "\n";
                currentLine = null;

            }
        }
        using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(paragraph, pnlText.Font, br, 5, 5);
        }
    }
```

The output: 
[one sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdgjZ.png) [whole paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X74Zn.png)

I am dumbstruck, it makes no sense for it to repeat like that.
I have tried using String Builder and replacing DisplayText.Length with a number and it still doesn't work right. Using foreach and drawing each char seperately works, albeit messes up spacing.

Also initially I didn't have "paragraph" string and I simply drew each line inside the loop, but that somehow caused the end of the text to be cut off and pasted at the very beginning which is even more insane. I am getting suspicious my computer is possessed with deamons.

Comment: Reset both currentLine and paragraph at the start of this method

Comment: It helps sort off. Setting both to null before the loop results in the string being drawn once, however it cuts off last five characters. Setting only paragraph to null somehow moves last 4 characters in front of the text and doesn't display 7 additional characters from the bottom.

Comment: After the loop, add the latest currentLine to the paragraph

Comment: Omg thanks. Works. Interesting that I had to null the currentLine and paragraph just before the loop even though I had declared them as null earlier.

Comment: Declaring as null works only for the first call of your method, after that they contain the latest values

Comment: What I didn't realize is that the paint event is somehow called more than once, as I have not done so deliberately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void pnlText_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pnlText.Font = new Font("Calibri", 14, FontStyle.Regular);
        SizeF lineSize = new SizeF();
        currentLine = null;
        paragraph = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < DisplayText.Length; i++)
        {
            currentLine += DisplayText[i];

            lineSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(currentLine, pnlText.Font);
            if (DisplayText[i].ToString() == " " && lineSize.Width >= 820)
            {

                paragraph += currentLine + "\n";
                currentLine = null;

            }
        }
        paragraph += currentLine;
        using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(paragraph, pnlText.Font, br, 5, 5);
        }
    }
```

Followed Hans Keﬆing advice and now it works. Something is calling the paint event more than once, hence the strings are not null to begin with.

Comment: The `Paint` event is called every time the form needs to be redrawn, this can be because you minimized it, moved it, covered it with another form, or because some control invalidates the entire form.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `paragraph` variable has a shared state. Verify you reset the state for each button click like that:

```
private void pnlText_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pnlText.Font = new Font("Calibri", 14, FontStyle.Regular);
        SizeF lineSize = new SizeF();

        paragraph = ""; // that should reset the paragraph variable between invocations

        for (int i = 0; i < DisplayText.Length; i++)
        {
            currentLine += DisplayText[i];

            lineSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(currentLine, pnlText.Font);
            if (DisplayText[i].ToString() == " " && lineSize.Width >= 820)
            {

                paragraph += currentLine + "\n";
                currentLine = null;

            }
        }
        using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(paragraph, pnlText.Font, br, 5, 5);
        }
    }
```

Or simply define it inside the `pnlText_Paint` method

Hope it helps :)